# how to reactively render external array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I made a small library to track the loading of all my api calls.
It basically is an array which contains objects describing one loading process. I import this library into a Single File Component to make calls to it. I then pass the array from the library to a child component and want to render all my objects in the array (the loading statuses). I see the data updating in Vue Devtools on the child component, however it is not updated in the page.

What i tried:

- passing the vue instance from the parent component and use $set to update the array
- using array.splice to update the array
- creating a new object with Object.assign, update the new object and then update the array (splice/$set)
- passing a key and updating this key when updating thew object
- calling methods in the library in the console

sample updating function:

```
function _finish(name, descFinished) {
        const i = _loaders.findIndex(l => l.name == name);
        if(i < 0) throw new NameNotFoundException(name);
        let loader = Object.assign({}, _loaders[i]);
        if(descFinished != undefined) loader.descFinished = descFinished;
        loader.loading = false;
        loader.error = false;
        loader.endTime = new Date();
        vm.$set(_loaders, i, loader);
        return _loaders[i];
}
```

I pass to the child component like this

```
<loading-status v-if="loadstatus" :statuses="loadstatus.getAllLoaders()"></loading-status>
```

child component looks this this

```
<template>
    <div v-if="statuses">
        <div v-for="status in statuses" :key="status.name">
            <div>
                {{ status.loading == true ? 'true' : 'false' }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'loading-status',
    props: {
        statuses: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image of the array not being reactive on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIeoH.png)

some more information that may be useful:

the library structure:

```
function loadmanager(vueinstance) {
    //library internals here
    // for example my array i want to render:
    let _loaders = [];
    var publicInterface() {
        //public accesable functions here
        //i call this to pass the array to my child component
        getAllLoaders() {
            return _loaders;
        }
    }
    return publicInterface;
}
exports.makeLoadManager = loadmanager;
```

i import the library in the vue SFC and call it in the mounted hook

```
import loadhelper from "../../helpers/Loadstatus.js";
...
data() {
    return {
        loadstatus: null
    }
}
...
mounted() {
    this.loadstatus = loadhelper.makeLoadManager(this);
}
```

My question boils down to: How do I reactively render or correctly update an array from a js library in vue.

I would be happy to provide more information if that helps answering my question.

Comment: What about transform your external lib into a vuex module?

Comment: if possible i would like to keep it an external library so i can reuse it in other projects.

Comment: If your only requirement its the portability you can make a [vuex plugin](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html)

Comment: this seems interesting and if nothing else pops up i will try it out. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your library is creating (and managing) an array of "loaders", simplest thing you can do is define empty reactive array in your Vue component's data and in `mounted` hook assign a reference to your's library array into it. Like this:

```js
import LoadingStatus from "./components/LoadingStatus";
import loadhelper from "./helpers/LoadManager.js";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    LoadingStatus
  },
  data() {
    return {
      statuses: []
    };
  }
  mounted() {
    this.statuses = loadhelper.getAllLoaders();
  }
};
```

Vue takes the array provided by your library and makes it reactive. You can use template like this:

```html
<LoadingStatus :statuses="statuses"/>
```

See the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-sf23v)

As long as both Vue and your "load manager" are working with the same array (reference), its all good. I'v added `setTimeout` callback into `LoadManager` to demonstrate that changes "from the outside of Vue" to the array will make Vue component re-render....

Comment: That is the perfect solution for me, I could not have asked for a better answer. Thank you.